# How can I get the token and simultaneously hide api credentials for google drive?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am writing a google drive desktop application and I am using OAuth 2 to get credentials. I can get creds for just reading, but not changing files. As it is a desktop application, there is no site. It is written in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app, that I need to "supply a local redirect URI to handle responses from Google's authorization server". So, should the client also be a server and listening on some port locally? If I want to have the app verified, I need to provide Authorized domains and other stuff, but it is a desktop application, again. Or maybe there is a way to allow users to use the app, but with a warning on a consent screen for example for development purposes.
Also how to hide the credentials, that I use to get the token? If I publish the app with the credentials, everybody can just steal them and use them

Comment: Hello @photon, if you have a desktop application you will need to create the credentials of `web app` type and then provide the appropriate redirect URI. Does this work for your situation? Cheers!

Comment: it would work, though I would not like to share my credentials. Otherwise the users would have to generate their own ones, which is not convenient for them

Comment: Hello @photon, what do you mean by **I would not like to share my credentials**? When you use OAuth 2.0 for accessing Drive you are the only one who has the credentials. The users of the app have to authorize the application in question. Would you mind providing more details? And what exactly are you trying to achieve? Cheers!

Comment: thanks for answering, I just wanted to share the application. For example, in windows, you are not downloading Google Drive application, then go to https://console.cloud.google.com/, create an application, create credentials for the app and so on. You're just using your email and password. I just don't know how to do the same

Comment: Hello @photon, so you would like to develop a desktop drive application which later you would end up sharing? But how do you plan on sharing this app? Moreover, as I understood, you want to have a login process. But again, this has nothing to do with the credentials generated for **your** application. The users when they "log in" to your application will have to authorize the application and use their **own** credentials for accessing the app. So, would you mind providing more details about how **exactly** you plan on developing your app? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 I understand, it and I thought about sharing the same way as you described. I just thought maybe there is another way, anyway you're not authorizing the official Google Drive application and get your credentials. You just use your own email/password. And yes, if there is no such way, my users would just get their own credentials and use it

Comment: Hello @photon, if you plan on using the Drive API for your application, your users **will need** to authorize the app and review the permissions when using it even when logging in with their **own** credentials. Is this of help to you? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 okay than, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to develop a desktop application which will use the **Drive API** you will have to use credentials of the `web app` type for which you will later provide the appropriate `redirect URI`.

By using OAuth 2.0 in your application, you are the only one who has access to the credentials for the application - unless you share them.

According to the [Google OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2):

> You start by obtaining the OAuth 2.0 client credentials from the `Google API Console`. Then your client application requests an access token from the `Google Authorization Server`, extracts a token from the response, and sends the token to the `Google API` that you want to access.

For the login process, when the users will log-in to your application, they will use their **own credentials** and then they will have to authorize the application you have built in order to be able to use the **Drive API**.

#### Reference

- [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app);
- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2);

Comment: I understand it, just usability of such an application would suffer then. For example, when I install Dropbox, it opens a page in a browser where I write my login and password. After that I use it. Here users should go to Google API Console, create an application, consent page, credentials, then go back and show the credentials to the application, based on which it would create a token. There is actually "PasswordCredentialsToken", I might use it eventually